# how to run packaged TestNG file that packaged by `mvn package`?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

**My requirements**
I have test projects that write with TestNG, I want this project can be run in other isolate IDC cluster that without internet access.

**What I am trying ? **

1. I use command `mvn package` to package the project on my personal
   PC, and then copy all files include `target` folder to isolate
   machine, then run with `mvn test` but flowing error happend.

   [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5
   or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
   artifact descriptor for
   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not
   transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:9 from/to central
   (http://repo.{our-company-domain}/nexus/content/groups/alirepositiry/):
   repo.{our-company-domain}: Name or service not known: Unknown host
   repo.{our-company-domain}: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
2. I use off-line mode to run `mvn test -o` also with errors:

   [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.apache:apache:pom:9 is not available in the local repository. -> [Help 1]

I have already change the maven local repository to the folder I have copied to the isolate machine.

How can I run these projects in isolated environment ? Or the TestNG project can be package to a jar package, that I can run it with command : `java -jar {packagename}.jar`(I also tried, but the case can only run with maven plugin) ?

Anyone can help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had used the assembly plugin for this - had documented the process I used   @ this blogpost - https://niharikawhatsnext.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/running-maven-testng-tests-as-a-jar/

HTH